# Preseed install Ubuntu 18.04 with wireless PEAP authentication

Tags: networking, preseed

I am attempting to configure a preseed unattended install of Ubuntu 18.04.2.  Our system uses Intel iwlwifi drivers with a device name of wlp2s0.  Our wireless uses WPA & WPA2 Enterprise security with PEAP authentication and no certificate.  I enter a user name and password to authenticate to the wireless router.

I need the preseed verbiage to allow this.  Without network connection my install is failing when attempting to access mirrors for downloads.  Can someone please help?

[Wifi Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7pAu.png)

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  That other post is not about preseeding.  I need to know the d-i keywords to allow me to use my wireless to download packages during install.

Comment: I'm currently playing around with this myself, and I'm pretty sure I know now how to do that. If I forget to answer again during the next week, feel free to remind me. If I realize that I didn't figure it out, I'll delete this comment again

Comment: I actually had a user tell me a work around she used.  My pressed install stops to allow the user to input the disk encryption password.  At that point, you can use the drop down at the upper right corner of the screen to configure wireless.  It works perfectly and the updates get downloaded.

Comment: Manually entering the password is an option for me as well, because the partitioning as I want it cannot be done with the preseed anyway. But it seems so unexpectedly powerless... it feels like it should be possible

Comment: When I open a tty during the installation and run `sudo ip link set dev wlan0 up ; sudo nmcli d wifi connect MYSSID password MYPASSWORD` connecting works. I tried setting that as an `early_command`, which had no visible effect - also not in the `/var/log/casper.log`. Right now I'm trying to modify the `ubiquity` python script in the squashfs, but it seems like repackaging the squashfs is not trivial

Comment: I haven't tried modifying the squashfs.  I'm not sure your solution would work for me because this is for installing Ubuntu at work.  Normally, I handle it, but with new users being added to the team and others needing re-installs, they're having to do it on their own; with the aid of a handy user doc I whipped up.  So far so good.

Comment: Assuming I get somewhere, I will post the answer and then you can decide :) I mean, even if it's just you who is able to handle it - you'd only have to built one iso and then they can flash that on the usb stick and all is well

Comment: I did it! I got it to autoconnect to a WPA2 network. I'll write an answer in the next few days.

Comment: I still have an unexpected problem though, so I'll try to fix that first

Answer (score 1):

I expect you're familiar with many of those steps as you are already preseeding. I'm still trying to make this a comprehensive answer.

Please note that the main part of this answer will be about WPA2 networks in general and not focusing on PEAP.

---

#### `preseed/netcfg` Does Not Work

> Preseeding keys for the following installer components will not be
>   used in Ubiquity, usually because they do not fit with Ubiquity's mode
>   of operation:
>
> **netcfg**
>   LVM and RAID partitioning
>   base-installer
>   pkgsel/tasksel
>   finish-install
>
> [Source: UbiquityAutomation (last edited 2019-07-12 07:07:21 by tsimonq2)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityAutomation)

From the logs in `/var/log/installer/debug` I can tell you that it seems like `netcfg/get_hostname` still seems to be considered though. Still, that means that we can not go the way that worked in older versions and specify the connection in the preseed file like

```
# wlp3s0b1 would be the device-specific wifi interface
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select wlp3s0b1
d-i netcfg/wireless_show_essids select manual
d-i netcfg/wireless_essid string myWifiName
d-i netcfg/wireless_essid_again string myWifiName
d-i netcfg/wireless_security_type select wpa
```

#### `preseed/early_command` Does Not Work

`preseed/early_command` is executed from casper. I have tried connecting to the wifi from there and the command does not seem to work there yet.
Of course `preseed/late_command` does also not work for us, because it happens later than the mirror settings. But if you'd only require internet after the installation for some other late commands, this way would be easier than what I'm about to explain.

### Modifying the Ubiquity Installer to give us a third option

> **[Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityAutomation)**
>   Evan needs to add a "a bit later than early command" preseed variable so that testing scripts can run once the desktop is available.
>   UbiquityAutomation (last edited 2019-07-12 07:07:21 by tsimonq2)

Well, Evan isn't here, so let's do it ourselves!

#### Mount the Original Iso and preseed it

```bsh
# mount iso readonly because it is readonly anyhow
sudo mount -o loop -t iso9660 ~/ubuntu.iso /mnt/myiso -o ro
# copy data to a writeable directory
mkdir ~/Downloads/iso.new
cp -ra /mnt/myiso/* ~/Downloads/iso.new
```

Apply your usual preseeding. I did it by adding a file to `iso.new/preseeding` that I reference in the boot arguments in `iso.new/isolinux/isolinux.cfg`.

Here is my `isolinux.cfg`. I haven't modified the start of it, and just appended the part starting from `label install`. You could also do that in `menu.cfg` or `txt.cfg` (which gets transitively included). In those files, you should also find similar entries you could use as a model.

```
# file ~/Downloads/iso.new/isolinux/isolinux.cfg
path
include menu.cfg
default install
prompt 1
timeout 50
ui gfxboot bootlogo

label install
  menu label ^LucidBrot 18.04. Hello World
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append auto=true file=/cdrom/preseed/my.seed boot=casper debug-ubiquity automatic-ubiquity initrd=/casper/initrd DEBCONF_DEBUG=5 debian-installer/locale=en_US.UTF-8 keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=ch languagechooser/language-name=English countrychooser/shortlist=CH localechooser/supported-locales=en_US.UTF-8
```

Note that even though I will be booting from a USB Stick, the path prefix is still `/cdrom`.
Also note that you won't need all of those options. You can safely remove any of the language or keyboard options. The two debug options are optional but help with logging. The remainder are important, including `automatic-ubiquity`.

Of course, the `file=` should point to your preseed file.

#### Filesystem Terminology

There are multiple filesystems.

1. The filesystem you are running all these commands in
2. The iso we mounted on `/mnt/myiso` and copied the contents of over to `~/Downloads/iso.new`. It contains some information for the bootloader.
3. A `~/Downloads/iso.new/casper/initrd` file which contains an initial ram filesystem that will be booted into once you select "Install Ubuntu" in grub.
4. A `~/Downloads/iso.new/casper/filesystem.squashfs` file which contains a compressed filesystem. This filesystem will be chrooted into after some initial setup done in the initramfs. Once that is up, it's possible to log into a tty by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> (or <kbd>F3</kbd>) and enter `ubuntu` as the username.
   The squashfs contains scripts for ubiquity - the installer.

Open The Squashfs

```
# isohybrid and unmksquashfs
sudo apt-get install syslinux-utils squashfs-tools
# unpack the squashfs to a new dir
mkdir ~/Downloads/squashy && cd ~/Downloads/squashy
sudo unsquashfs ~/Downloads/iso.new/casper/filesystem.squashfs
# now we have a new directory "squashfs-root"
```

#### Modify Ubiquity

We have several options, judging by the amount of scripts lying around in `~/Downloads/squashy/squashfs-root/` but I will go with the plugin manager, because it happens to be exectued fairly early: Before debian-installer gets the locale, but definitely after the initramfs part. That can be verified by adding print statements and viewing `/var/log/installer/debug`.

So open `~/Downloads/squashy/squashfs-root/usr/bin/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/plugin_manager.py` (I'd say as root, but not sure if that's necessary) and add the import statement `import subprocess` after all the other imports at the start of the file. Then navigate to line 42 where the function `def load_plugins():` should be defined.
Here what I inserted at the start of it, though the print statements are only for the logs and can be skipped.

```py
def load_plugins():
    print("flappy plugin_manager: load_plugins()")
    mywifires = subprocess.run("/cdrom/preseed/inb4.sh", stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print("flappy stdout wifi: {}".format(mywifires))
    print("flappy usr/lib/bin/ubiquity/ubiquity/plugin_manager: post-wifi", file=sys.stderr)

    modules = []
```

#### Set Up `inb4.sh`

It is now possible for us to run arbitrary bash commands at the start of the installation by entering them into `~/Downloads/iso.new/preseed/inb4.sh`.
Since I simply want to connect to a normal WPA2 network, here's how mine looks (make sure you use your own interface as `ip link` reports it instead of my `wlp3s0b1`):

```bsh
# file iso.new/preseed/inb4.sh
#!/bin/sh
set -ux
sudo ip link set dev wlp3s0b1 up
sudo nmcli d wifi connect myWiFiHotspot password MyPassw0rd
```

It should not be too hard to get that working with a PEAP network. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/334675/66736), [this gist](https://gist.github.com/tibyte/085a7886f47dd0e9d9653366787cd393) or [this blogpost](https://blog.khmersite.net/2018/08/connect-to-a-wpa2-enterprise-connection-using-nmcli/) which all rely on the same tool as I do (`nmcli`, which is already installed):

> ```
> nmcli> set 802-1x.eap peap  
> nmcli> set 802-1x.phase2-auth mschapv2  
> nmcli> set 802-1x.identity myusername
> nmcli> set 802-1x.password mypassword  
> nmcli> set wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-eap  
> nmcli> save 
> nmcli> activate
> ```

> ```
> nmcli connection add \
>  type wifi con-name "MySSID" ifname wlp3s0 ssid "MySSID" -- \
>  wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-eap 802-1x.eap tls 802-1x.identity "USERNAME" \
>  802-1x.ca-cert ~/ca.pem 802-1x.client-cert ~/cert.pem \
>  802-1x.private-key-password "..." 802-1x.private-key ~/key.pem
> ```

#### Make `inb4.sh`executable

Just to be safe.

```bsh
sudo chmod a+rx ~/Downloads/iso.new/preseed/inb4.sh
```

#### Pack Squashfs

Make sure you currently don't have a file called `filesystem.squashfs` in your `squashy` directory, because that will cause the next commands to create `/dev_1` instead of `/dev` and such things...

```bsh
cd ~/Downloads/squashy
sudo rm filesystem.squashfs
sudo mksquashfs squashfs-root/ filesystem.squashfs -b 1024k -comp xz -Xbcj x86 -e sudo cp filesystem.squashfs ../iso.new/casper/filesystem.squashfs
```

This command will take about 10 minutes on my laptop - be patient.
I'm not certain if all those flags are needed. I copied them from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80305/mounting-a-squashfs-filesystem-in-read-write/80312#80312). Just make sure that you aren't accidentally excluding `/boot` by doing `-e boot`. [The ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch) implies that it works with less flags.

> **Compress the chroot**
>   If this Customised Remix is to potentially be
>   installed on some systems then the `/boot` folder will be needed. To
>   allow the Customised Cd to be an installer Cd, compress the entire
>   chroot folder with this command:
>
> `sudo mksquashfs chroot image/casper/filesystem.squashfs`
>   Then write the
>   `filesystem.size file`, which is needed by the installer:
>
> `printf $(sudo du -sx --block-size=1 chroot | cut -f1) >
>   image/casper/filesystem.size`
>   However, if it is not going to be
>   installed and is 'only' meant as a LiveCD then the `/boot` folder can be
>   excluded to save space on your iso image. The live system boots from
>   outside the chroot and so the `/boot` folder is not used.
>
> `sudo mksquashfs chroot image/casper/filesystem.squashfs -e boot` 
>   It is
>   important to note that if you are building a Karmic LiveCd on an
>   earlier system, you will need the `squashfs-tools` package from Karmic
>   or the LiveCD will not boot.

Because we did not modify any packages in the squashfs (aka chroot), I'm pretty certain that we don't need to perform the manifest step in the image below, but I guess it shouldn't hurt to at least perform the printf step in the quote above. And if you for some reason *did* modify packages, that is out of scope of this answer but I can recommend [this post](https://nathanpfry.com/how-to-customize-an-ubuntu-installation-disc/) and also [this one which considers gpg](https://www.neteye-blog.com/2018/06/custom-ubuntu-iso-image-for-unattended-and-offline-installation/).

> [image: explanation for modifying manifest]

#### Build the iso back together

```bsh
# copy the modified squashfs back to the iso filesystem data
sudo cp ~/Downloads/squashy/filesystem.squashfs ~/Downloads/iso.new/casper/filesystem.squashfs
# build iso. Again, the flags are beyond be, but they work
sudo mkisofs -J -l -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -z -iso-level 4 -c isolinux/isolinux.cat -o ~/Downloads/outputubuntu.iso -joliet-long iso.new
# make the iso bootable from an usb stick (it's only bootable from cdrom currently)
sudo isohybrid ~/Downloads/outputubuntu.iso
```

#### Flash it on a Stick!

I have made the mistake of using `dd` on `/dev/sda` when the stick was not plugged in, and that caused me a bit of pain until I realized I had to delete `/dev/sda` while the stick was plugged out to get it functioning again. To prevent that happening to you, we first make sure the stick is both plugged in and unmounted.
`sudo unmount /dev/sda1` should work after you plug the stick in, because ubuntu automounts it. If it does not, look at `lsblk`'s output and unmount the partition that is mounted. Be wary that your stick may be another device than `/dev/sda` and `dd` can be pretty brutal if you make mistakes.

```bsh
# plug usb stick in. Unmount it and flash the iso
cd ~/Downloads
sudo umount /dev/sda1 && sudo dd bs=4M if=ubuntuoutput.iso of=/dev/sda conv=fdatasync status=progress
```

The flag `conv=fdatasync` enusres that `dd` will only say it's finished when all the data has actually been written.
This command will take a few minutes, but is faster than the packing of the squashfs.

### Boot it!

Plug the stick into the device you want to install ubuntu on and boot it. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> on the grub screen if you'd like to verify that your preseed is actually being run. It should display the label you specified.

The wifi should automatically connect during the ubiquity install. If it does not, check out the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> tty to view the logs in `/var/log/casper.log` and `/var/log/installer/debug`. Since we set the debug level pretty high, you should see something if you had it print something - or just modify your commands to write their output to a file.